# Grouping a table frame into parts and summing over them

Tags: r

I have the following data frame d:

```
$id: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 ...
$given_answer: "A" "A" "B" "A" "B" ...
$correct_answer: "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" ...
```

id corresponds to the id of a student. Thus the first four columns in $given_answer are provided by student 1.

I wish to count up the number correct for each student.

```
table(d$correct_answer == d$given_answer)["TRUE"]
```

gives me the total correct answers across all students.
How do I split this up per student?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
table(d$correct_answer == d$given_answer,d$id)[2,]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
d <- data.frame(id=rep(1:3, each=4), given_answer=sample(LETTERS[1:2], 
  12, relace=TRUE), correct_answer=sample(LETTERS[1:2], 12, replace=TRUE))
```